# Linq any collection in any collection

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Entity Framework

I have a simple object with a well know structure

```
Order.Name
Order.ProductIds  List<int>
```

I need to get all the Orders which include at least 1 productId found in searchProductIds:

```
List<int> searchProductIds
```

I'm trying:

```
queryOrders.Where(e=>e.ProductIds.Any(???searchProductIds???));
```

Perhaps some kind of intersect?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Order.ProductIds` can't be stored in a database field, so it can't be a mapped property. How is this property populated? I ask, because it's relevant to know whether you're doing this in memory (as in LINQ to objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
queryOrders.Where(queryOrder => (queryOrder.ProductIds.Intersect(searchProductIds)).Any());
```

Comment: Hi Walker. the searchProducIDs are  a list of search products. I need a list of Orders that have at least one of those those searchProducts.